# OCaml default fold_left implementation: question about syntax

Tags: ocaml, fold

I'm learning OCaml. Currently, I'm going through some of the default iterator implementations for Lists and I'm a little confused about one part of `fold_left`.

```
let rec fold_left f accu l =
  match l with
    [] -> accu
  | a::l -> fold_left f (f accu a) l
```

The part I'm confused about is `(f accu a)`. I'll break it down to the extent of my understanding.

- `f` is the function passed to `fold_left` that should be applied to each element in the list.
- `accu` is the accumulator that keeps track of the folded sum.
- `a` is the element at the head of `l`, the list passed to `fold_left`.

Why is the accumulator being passed to `f`? Shouldn't it be the sum of the accumulator and the return value of `f a`?

And how does all of this return a single `int`, which is what the accumulator should be (assumedly)?

Comment: The point is that the function does not just need to be a straight sum. What if you wanted to multiply all the values in the list? Your way you describe wouldn't support that. `f` takes in the running total and current value and allows the user to select how to accumulate the values.

Comment: @clcto Oh, I might be misunderstanding fold, then. I thought of it as

`for(item in set) sum += func(item);`

but you're saying it is more like 

`for(item in set) sum func item;`

?

Comment: It would be more like `for (item in set) accu = func(accu, item)`, where `func(accu, item)` could be `accu + item`, in which case  `accu` would be a sum. Or it could be `accu * item`, in which case `accu` would be a product. Or it could be anything else you'd like. That's why it's called an accumulator, not just sum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A fold is completely general, it's not just for adding up numbers.

The function `f` can be any function that takes an accumulated value (of any type) and a new value from the list, and returns a new accumulated value. That's the only requirement.

You can imagine `fold_left f init [a; b; c; d]` as a short way to write this expression:

```
f (f (f (f init a) b) c) d
```

Again, `f` can be any function whose type is correct for the accumulated value and the list elements.